# Skeptics — Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

If you can find your name on the first two pages [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) (top 72 users, that is), I have some good news for you — **this is not a hoax**, [believe me!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oN2H.jpg) Note: [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-place_artifact) is completely unrelated to what you're about to read. <sub><sup><sub><sup>(˳^ ɜ^)˳～♪</sup></sub></sup></sub>

Recently, we, at Stack Overflow, have found a lot of boxes with old artefacts in them, left by some ancient civilisation! Though we still haven't determined the exact rituals for which these were used, we want to send them to you, as a small token of our appreciation for helping this site and community grow into what they are today! Inside each of these little boxes, we found:

**A T-SHIRT!**

[image: T-SHIRTS!!!!!!!]

**STICKERS!**

[image: STICKERS!!!!!!!]

Curious that these should match you recent redesign, right?

You should receive an e-mail from me later today with a link to a form: be sure to fill out the form as soon as you're able to do so! You'll have two weeks to do it, after which I'll close the form and start taking care of shipping everything! All in all, it should take the usual 6 to 8 weeks for the whole process to be completed, and the package delivered to you!

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag stored we can send to you for events and such!

**Thanks to all of you for making this site awesome!**

Comment: well, damn ;) did not make that cut (okay, wide margin)

Comment: It occurs to me, I never received my swag. (This isn't a complaint about not getting free stuff. I'm not that churlish. I'm guessing it was lost in the mail.)

Comment: Can you shoot me an e-mail about it, so I check with our vendor and can follow up with you, @Oddthinking?

Answer (score 11):

Just got the email about this.

Just so you know, page size in the user list differs depending on whether you're on the mobile or desktop site. Assuming you have the desktop site in mind, I can see that the user who just didn't make the cut, Sean Duggan, has been actively posting this month - today even - whereas my last contribution was in 2011. Much as I appreciate the initiative, I'd be happy to hand my spot over to someone who is actively contributing.

Comment: I edited the post to clarify how many users we have in mind for this. I'm ok with you forfeiting your swag in favour of Sean, so... just let me know if that's really what you'd rather do! ;)

Comment: It is! Thanks for the offer, though!

Comment: Cool. I'll let Sean know, then. Thanks!

Comment: Wow. Thanks! I have submitted my form.

Comment: And I got the T-shirt on Saturday, Again, thanks, David.

Answer (score 8):

Also, I hope also you could send an email to the member: [nomen agentis](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/25668/nomen-agentis?tab=profile).

Nomen offered around 6,150 worth of reputation to improve the quality of answers on this website, go nomen! The community won't forget.

[image]

Comment: I agree nomen agentis should get more due for his sharing of reputation and expected quality of answers!

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you for this token of appreciation, I'm sure the goodies will be awesome!

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for this kind and gentle gift.

Answer (score 2):

I received my T-shirt and stickers over the weekend. ^_^ Thanks!